# Exception in thread “main” java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm just a newbie in java, so please help me, i think the problem is in the switch stament

```
    String customer[]=new String[2];
    int old[]=new int[2];

    for(i=0; i<customer.length;i++){
        System.out.println("\nEnter information of customer#" +(i+1));
        System.out.print("Enter customer name"+(i+1)+":");
        customer[i]=data.readLine();
        System.out.print("Enter old reading of costumer#"+(i+1)+":");
        old[i]=Integer.parseInt(data.readLine());
                    }

            System.out.println("\n\nSample Menu");
        System.out.println("1. Display Transaction\n2.Pay Water Bill");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice:");
            choice=Integer.parseInt(data.readLine());
```

In this part the System.out.println(customer[i]+"."); is not working

```
    switch(choice){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("This is to display the transaction!");
                            System.out.println(customer[i]+"."); \
                   break;
        case 2:
                 System.out.println("This is to pay the water bill!");
                break;
        default:                                                        System.out.println("Exit`!");
            break;

            }
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you exit your loop, the value of `i` is 2, not 1.

> The increment expression is invoked after each iteration through the
>   loop.

So when accessing `System.out.println(customer[i]+".");` you go out of bounds since the last element of your array is at index 1 (arrays are 0 base indexed).

If you take this snippet of code:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){}
System.out.print(i);
```

It outputs 2.

Comment: @user3460287 What do you want to do by `System.out.println(customer[i]+".");` ?

Comment: i need to print the customer and old

Comment: @user3460287 But which customer? The first one or the second one?

Comment: the first one

The output must be this

Enter information#1
Enter Customer name: ME
Enter old reading: 25
Enter new reading: 59

Welcome to Water Billing System
1. Display Transaction
2. Pay Water Bill
Enter your choice: 1 

Customer Name: // i need to print this

Comment: @user3460287 If you want to print the first customer, use `System.out.println(customer[0]+".");`. If you want to print the second one use `System.out.println(customer[1]+".");`.

Answer (score 0):

At that point variable `i` has incremented to `2` So you would have to reset it first. Ofcourse you get IOOB exception because you are referencing missing place in array (only places `0` and `1` exist)

Comment: Put `i == 0` before the switch, for example. Although this code makes no sense to me.

Comment: it works but no one word is appearing, i need to print the customer i entered

Answer (score 0):

This is how your code works :

```
for(i=0; i<customer.length;i++){ 
   ............................
   ............................
}

Hence, i takes values :

i     is (i < customer.length)
0           YES
1           YES
2            NO  <LOOP BREAKS>
```

Now, when it comes to the switch statement, the following happens:

```
switch(2) { //ALWAYS
..........
..........
}
```

Hence, the `switch(1)` case, or the `System.out.println(customer[i]+".")` is never reached. It's quite a common mistake.

What you need is a do while loop for your menu.

So :

```
// Initialize Values
for(i=0; i<customer.length;i++){ 
   ............................
   ............................
}

// Loop through the Options

do {
    // ASK FOR USER INPUT AS YOU ARE DOING

    switch(choice) { //ALWAYS
    ..........
    ..........
    }

} while(choice != 1 || choice != 2);
```

The `do while` ensures that no matter what, your command will be executed for the menu, when it is given. So for example, in the `do while`, your `default` exit statement will always be printed.